# comparing strings using equality sign in C programming

Tags: c, string, strcmp

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[] = "ComputerProgram";
    char str2[] = "ComputerProgram";
    (str1==str2)? (printf("Equal")):(printf("unequal"));
    return 0;
}
```

The answer according to me should be equal but it comes out to be unequal.
However if I use `strcmp(str1,str2) == 0` answer comes out to be equal. How is it working in `==` case.? Also, I tried to print the ASCII values of `srt1` and `str2`, they came out to be different. So I think that might be the reason. Now the problem is how does `==` work for strings?

Comment: you need to use function [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) for string comparision

Answer (score 3):

Your arrays `str1` and `str2` will decay to pointers to their first elements when you compare them. That is, you compare two pointers that will *never* be equal.

In short, your comparison `str1 == str2` is equal to `&str1[0] == &str2[0]`.

What `strcmp` does differently is that is compares each character in the first string against each corresponding character in the other string, in a loop.

Comment: Thanks .. Just checked the adresses and yes they are different.. thanks alot

Comment: Instead of repeatedly answering common FAQs, you could open up the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), scroll down to FAQ, find the section called strings, find the relevant canonical duplicate and then close vote.

Answer (score 0):

`str1==str2` is comparing the addresses of the strings, not the strings themselves.`strcmp` will go to these addresses and compare all characters.

Comment: @Michael Walz oh, i meant strcmp will fix it